# MahApps window move on mouse left-click

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, mahapps.metro

I am using Mahapps window in wpf application. I have drooped on the layout two controls: a Treeview and Listview however I am seeing an unwanted behavior, which is when I left-click and hold on free space on both controls (just bellow some entries) I can drag a window anywhere on the screen. Is there a way to disable that functionality? thank you

Comment: have you tried `UseNoneWindowStyle="True"`?

Comment: Yes, and its almost do the job, however since I need to hide the toolbar. I can really move the window once it is showed.

Comment: So should I post this as an answer or not?

Comment: hmm ..I still not having the right effect.. since I cant move the window at all now

Comment: you can add a menu item that toggle the value of `UseNoneWindowStyle`

Comment: Unfortunately this is not good solution for my case. Just wondering why its happening only with Listview and Treeview controls.Ideally I woould expect that they Overlay an Window object

Comment: UseNoneWindowStyle="True" work for me

Answer (score 0):

There will be no option to disable the functionality of  mahapps window. Its better you write your own window(as borderlesswindow) and inherit styles from Mahapps.metro.

Comment: Hmm.. I am not after disabling the whole functionality, I just need not implement it on the actual control